# Objective HTML Postmaster – send by date, not add/edit entry

Tags: postmaster, objective-html

I've been working on solving this problem for a while, and hoping someone can help me come up with a solution.

Basically what I'm doing is creating an EE Grid field with a title, date, and description. The way I want Postmaster to trigger is based on the Grid date field.

When a date is 5 days in the future I want a reminder email to be sent. I can't seem to figure out how to do this? Currently I have the Grid field name "calendar", and for testing I put this in the "**Post date specific**" field of the Postmaster Parcel setting:

```
{calendar:date format="%m-%d-%Y"}
```

However, nothing happens if I add an row with today's date? If I change the trigger to "Edit" an email gets sent, but it also gets sent every time one of the rows is edited or a new row added to the calendar Grid field? Not what I want, I only want it to trigger 5 days prior to the date entered? How can I accomplish this?

I believe it should be possible with Postmaster, but can't seem to figure out how to do it??

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create this as a Postmaster "Notification" rather than a "Parcel", which gives you a URL which you then ping with a scheduled cron job.

When creating the Notification, you should be able to fetch the date from the channel grid data inside the "Post Date Specific" field. (Even though Postmaster only gives you a tiny text input, you can put any EE template code inside these fields).

Comment: Thanks James, I'll give that a shot and see how I get on...

Comment: This is not working still. The thing I really need is to send "-X Days", not "+X days". Is this possible? Because it doesn't seem to work. I can get the notification to fire using the date specific, but the thing is it's a reminder, so all date will be in the future, hence I need to send it X days before, not after. Any further help appreciated...